# UIScrollview doesn't scroll iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm creating several scroll views in one view that scroll horizontally. The following code works fine:

```
-(void)updateSection {
    builder = [NSMutableArray array];
    float xPosition = 0;
    float xposbut = 100;

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - 69)];

    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:scrollView];

    for (int i = 1; i < itemArticleArray.count; i++) {
        ItemView *item = [ItemView loadNibs];
        item.frame = CGRectMake(xposbut, 10, item.frame.size.width, item.frame.size.height);

        xPosition += scrollView.frame.size.width + 2;
        xposbut += 500;
        UIView *seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xposbut - 50, 4, 2, scrollView.frame.size.height - 8)];
        [scrollView addSubview:seperatorView];
        xPosition += scrollView.frame.size.width + 4;

        [scrollView addSubview: item];
        [builder addObject:item];
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xposbut, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

However, when I change the 8th line of code to the following:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - 69)];
```

It cause the layout to look fine, but the scroll views do then not scroll at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Which line of code you changed ?

Comment: Sorry, I've editied the post above now

Comment: At least one of the `contentSize` dimensions has to be bigger than `scrollView`'s own size for to be able to scroll somewhere.

Comment: @AdamAltinkaya: are you using iPhone or iPad. Set a background color for scroll view and check it's position

Comment: @rokjarc - I am only changing y ordinates though?

Comment: I just noticed you call `[self addSubview:scrollView];` twice. Fix that - ditch the first one - and try again...

Comment: I've tried with either one of them taken out, and it hasn't made any difference?

Answer (score 3):

you set the `contentSize.height` to the `scrollView.frame.size.height` and so the `scrollView` cant scroll. you have to set the `contentSize` to the total height of you `scrollView`, including the not visible area. The frame is only the area on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content size for the scroll view. The content size should be greater than frame.size, then only the scroll view will scroll. And also enable scrolling.

Use the code

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(CGFloat width, CGFloat height);
```

Height should be greater than scrollView.frame.size.height and add contents inside scrollview beyond the scrolview's frame.

Comment: But I want it to scroll vertically rather than horizontally?

Comment: Creating a scrollview with contentsize.height greater than frame.size.height will allow you to scroll vertically. Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollview` will scroll when content size is bigger then frame size. In your code you set content size equal to frame size that's why your scrollview is not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You must give the scroll some space to work so check this out:

1. Create the scroll in the storyboard
2. Create an outlet for the scroll
3. And the in the `.m` file you must paste these lines

The code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    yourScroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    yourScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height*2);
}

/*
 * yourScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(your desired scroll width, your desired scroll height);
 * The values must be bigger than the viewController size
 */
```